# i dont understand the :self return type in php

Tags: php, return

i am reading Brent Roose's book Laravel, beyond crud.
on page 57, he states this example:

```
class InvoiceQueryBuilder extends Builder
{
      public function wherePaid(): self
     {
       return $this->whereState('status', Paid::class);
     }
}
```

I am confused however about the :self - what is this returning?

Answer (score 3):

In this context, `self` is just a shortcut for whatever the current class is. So this:

```
class InvoiceQueryBuilder extends Builder
{
     public function wherePaid(): self
     {
         return $this->whereState('status', Paid::class);
     }
}
```

Is the same as this:

```
class InvoiceQueryBuilder extends Builder
{
     public function wherePaid(): InvoiceQueryBuilder 
     {
         return $this->whereState('status', Paid::class);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`self` is specified when you are returning an instance of the current class you're working in - in this case inside that method `whereState` - it is probably doing something and then returning `$this`.

This is useful for situations where you want to chain methods, ex:

```php
$invoice = new InvoiceBuilder();
$invoice->wherePaid()->whereInvoiceEmailed();
```